# System.OutOfMemoryException is coming while using BackgroundWorker class

Tags: c#, datagridview, out-of-memory, backgroundworker

I am using a background worker to update the rows in datagridview control. As I am filling the rows I am getting System.OutOfMemoryException after 16,00,000 rows.  Why it is coming?
when this exception comes usually?

could anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

Comment: 16 millions ??? Maybe should should consider use pagination ...

Comment: See the `Remarks` section of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for common causes. Clearly you've got too many rows.

Comment: This exception comes usually when the System is out of memory as indicated by the Exception.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-end-of-pagination/ There is absolutely no reasonable reason to show an end user 16 million rows. They will never ever read it. Code to your audience.

Comment: make the rows smaller

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle 1.6 million rows, you need to handle them in batches. You cannot have them in memory all at once. Especially using a user control that adds a lot of overhead for displaying those rows.

See how many you *can* fit into your RAM. Do not put them in a user control. Handle them in batches of whatever size your database can handle best (from my experience that's somewhere from 1K to 10K rows in a bulk/batch).